Is there a kafka image available where i can create and play around all the connection types supported by kafka?
Is there a kafka image(free) available where i can create and play around all the connection types supported by kafka?
I want to try various connection modes like:-
SASL, PLAIN, SCRAM, GSSAPI (Kerberos), OAUTHBEARER and combination of SSL.

By "image", I assume you mean Docker? Yes, there are several in Dockerhub. Have you not found them? All are free to pull and should support the listeners you've specified

:) Dockerhub is not accessible in the org :)...

If not accessible, then how are you expected to pull any image? And did you try apache/kafka:3.7.0?
